# Why does my denoised image get darker after using non local means algorithm and why is the noise not reduced significantly?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise-reduction

I have implemented the naive version of non local means without integral images.
First image acquisition:

```
row = 10;
col = 10;

% Patchsize - make sure if code works for different values
patchSize = 4;

% Search window size - make sure if code works for different values
searchWindowSize = 10;

image = imread('r.jpg');
new=imnoise(image,'gaussian');
imshow(new)
ws=floor(searchWindowSize/2);
ps=floor(patchSize/2);
new= padarray(new, [searchWindowSize,searchWindowSize], 'both');
new= padarray(new, [patchSize,patchSize], 'both');
```

Now, the main non local means function:

```
unew=zeros(size(new,1),size(new,2));
for i=1+ws+ps:size(new,1)-ws-ps
    for j=1+ws+ps:size(new,2)-ws-ps
        sear=new(i-ws:i+ws,j-ws:j+ws);
        %imshow(new(i-ws:i+ws,j-ws:j+ws))
        sear=padarray(sear,[ps,ps],'both');
        patch=new(i-ps:i+ps,j-ps:j+ps);
        dis=[];
        ind=1;
        sums=0;
        for ii=1+ps:size(sear,1)-ps
            for jj=1+ps:size(sear,1)-ps
                patchn=new(ii-ps:ii+ps,jj-ps:jj+ps);
                ssd=(patchn-patch).*2;
                psum=0;
                for mj=1:patchSize
                    for gj=1:patchSize
                        psum= psum+ssd(mj,gj);
                    end
                end
                dis(ind)=psum;
                sums=sums+exp(-max(dis(ind)*dis(ind)-2*0.1*0.1,0)/0.75*0.75);                

                ind=ind+1;
            end
        end
        new(i,j)=sums;
    end
end
```

My initial image:

[image]

My final image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with the code. Here is a non-exhaustive list:

- You don’t do anything with color, it looks like your code is written for a grey-value image. But you put a color image through it. Consequently, only the red channel is modified.
- You write into the same image you read from. You cannot do this, as you’re using a combination of input and output pixels to generate the next output pixel. Instead, read from one image, write to another one.
- A weighted mean is computed by summing `value*weight`, and then dividing by the sum of the weights at the end. You don’t do this division.
- You crop your search area from your image, then pad it. This makes no sense. You should crop a larger region from your image.
- You keep an array `dis`, you write to it, but you don’t make use of it. That is, you write a new element, then only read this new element; you never go back and look at the older values. Why does this array exist?
- Your inner two loops can be written as `psum = sum(ssd(:))`.
- `ssd` is twice the difference. You probably want to look at the square difference, or the absolute difference.

Comment: https://ideone.com/P1Kqbg  I fixed the first two points. Could you help me fix the third point(weighted mean)?

Comment: I implemented the weighing too. Could you please suggest if my code is correct?: https://ideone.com/7497Ht

Comment: @UjjayantaBhaumik: Instead of `rcn(i,j)=rcn(i,j)-sums/sums2`, I think you need to do just `rcn(i,j)=sums/sums2`. But you now have `new` and `unew` that are not used, so you're reading from the unpadded input image instead of the padded `new`. And your `patchn` doesn't take into account `i` and `j`. There's a lot of work to be done here... Also, please, don't copy-paste the same code 3 times, write a function and call it 3 times. It's a bit more work upfront, but a lot less work down the line.

Comment: Not that this is necessarily good code, but you could compare your implementation to the one by the authors of the original non-local means paper: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13176-non-local-means-filter

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you suggest me a good source for non local means using integral images too?

Comment: Would you please look at my integral image implementation: https://ideone.com/UjExW0